How do I make grouping work with and React and the konva-react library?
Working on a simple drag and drop editor. I am adding images:
const addImage = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (event) => {
      const img = new window.Image();
      img.src = event.target.result;
      img.onload = () => {
        const aspect = img.width / img.height;
        const width = 200;
        const newImage = {
          id: `image-${Date.now()}`,
          type: 'image',
          x: 50,
          y: 50,
          width: width,
          height: width / aspect,
          image: img,
          opacity: 1,
        };
        setObjects([...objects, newImage]);
      };
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };

And this works well. I have done the same for text, but for this purpose, I am trying to group two images.
const groupSelected = () => {
    if (selectedIds.length < 2) return;
  
    const groupedNodes = selectedIds.map((id) =>
      layerRef.current.findOne(`#${id}`)
    );
  
    // Create a new Konva.Group instance
    const group = new Konva.Group({
      id: `group-${Date.now()}`,
      draggable: true,
    });
  
    // Add each selected node to the group
    groupedNodes.forEach((node) => {
      group.add(node);
    });
  
    // Add the group to the layer
    layerRef.current.add(group);
    layerRef.current.batchDraw();
  
    // Clear out the individual nodes that are now grouped
    const remainingObjects = objects.filter((obj) => !selectedIds.includes(obj.id));
    setObjects([...remainingObjects, { id: group.id(), type: 'group' }]);
  
    // Set the group as selected
    setSelectedIds([group.id()]);
  };

and my renderObject:
const renderObject = (obj) => {
    switch (obj.type) {
      case 'image':
        return (
          <Image
            key={obj.id}
            id={obj.id}
            x={obj.x}
            y={obj.y}
            width={obj.width}
            height={obj.height}
            image={obj.image}
            draggable
            onDragStart={handleDragStart}
            onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
            onTransformEnd={handleTransformEnd}
            opacity={obj.opacity}
          />
        );
      case 'text':
        return (
          <Text
            key={obj.id}
            id={obj.id}
            x={obj.x}
            y={obj.y}
            text={obj.text}
            fontSize={obj.fontSize}
            fontFamily={obj.fontFamily}
            fill={obj.fill}
            width={obj.width}
            height={obj.height}
            align={obj.align}
            draggable
            onDragStart={handleDragStart}
            onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
            onTransformEnd={handleTransformEnd}
            fontStyle={obj.fontStyle}
            textDecoration={obj.textDecoration}
          />
        );
      case 'group':
        // Check if obj.objects exists and is an array, and provide an empty array if undefined
        return (
          <Group
            key={obj.id}
            id={obj.id}
            x={obj.x}
            y={obj.y}
            draggable
            onDragStart={handleDragStart}
            onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
            onTransformEnd={handleTransformEnd}
          >
            {(obj.objects || []).map(renderObject)}
          </Group>
        );
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };

When I group two or more selected objects, they just disappear.
Been struggling on grouping for days. I can make simple versions work but when I try to work it into this, I cannot make it work no matter what I do.
Any help would be much appreciated.

You don't need to use new Konva.Group as you must render whole scene just using react/jsx. Make a demo of your issue.
